# Getting LockAcquisitionException Exception in delete call, by using below code

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

While I call the method below, hibernate throws LockAcquisitionException.

**Method to delete records** :

```
@Transactional
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM business_user where user_id in :userIds and business_id = :businessId",nativeQuery = true)
void deleteAllByUserIdsAndBusinessId(@Param("userIds") List<Integer> userIds,@Param("businessId") Integer businessId);
```

**StackTrace** :

```
021-04-26 20:18:48.149 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-199] c.b.b.w.e.h.APIExceptionHandler :Exception occured : 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not execute statement
    ...
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table locked by another transaction. (Maby this happens while you have a deadlock in some thread that cannot release database lock)

PS: Default isolation level of `@Transaction` depends on the datastore you use ([link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html#DEFAULT)), check what level it is and if you need to try to down transaction isolation level. And try to research deadlocks in your program.

Comment: The default isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ`. I checked the logs and found dead lock in other flows, but the timing is different of *DeadLock* and *Lock wait time out*. 

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction.  

DB versioning and lower down isolation level is solution ? 
How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Do you research what CRUD method cause deadlock?
PS: timing is different because `Lock wait time out` throws after some time out when a transaction cannot lock db or table.

Comment: Yes when I tried to save data, it get caught in dead lock .

**Apr 27, 2021 19:55:04.792**
at com.birdeye.business.service.impl.BusinessActivityServiceImpl.setAndLogStatus(BusinessActivityServiceImpl.java:695)Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

**Apr 27, 2021 01:48:48.149**
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.deleteAllByUserIdsAndBusinessId(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: There is 18 hours gap between these two.

Comment: Hmm, sorry I cannot help you with so pity information. I think you should catch the point why you get so long lock on the table.